# Anchor link to ID on same page not working

Tags: html, css

I know this has been asked already but i went over all existing threads but still can't fix the issue. On my local machine all anchor tags are working well and when i click on a link it jumps to the section. But since i deploy the site it suddenly stops working and nothing happen when i click on the link. 
Here is a link to my git repository. 
https://github.com/Marburc/seventis/tree/gh-pages

Already tried the name attribute instead of id.

```
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#angebot">Angebot</a>
   </li>
  <section id="angebot">
...
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery is not loading due to 'Mixed Content' errors. You are requesting resources of HTTP but your site is loaded over HTTPS. So to protect the user chrome blocks it. The solution is just to change it to https like so:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And without the jquery some of the other plugins like the animate function for smooth scrolling was not working.

It's at the bottom of the page.